# Why is "is" used rather than "are" as the form of "be" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Why is "is" used rather than "are" as the form of "be" in this sentence?

> ...carrying out attacks on the VC's residence, office, vandalism as well as disrupting classes and university activities in the name of movement ***is*** also one kind of terror act.

Comment: Will you please post the full original sentence? That might provide some crucial information.

Comment: Because it's a poorly constructed sentence fragment from which nothing can be determined.  Voting to close.  Questions without effort may get answers without effort.

Answer (score 0):

The use of ellipses at the start of the quotation in the question indicate what's quoted is not a complete sentence. It's possible that providing the complete sentence would change its interpretation.

But assuming it's not a mistake (or that the ellipses aren't there and what is quoted is the complete sentence), then the essential subject of the sentence is *carrying out attacks*, which is singular:

> Carrying out attacks (…) **is** also one kind of terror act.

It's a single (conceptual) activity that can be composed of multiple parts.

It is the same as all of these:

> - Carrying out the garbage **is** a household chore.
> - Drinking and driving **is** illegal.
> - Leaving work early, not telling anyone, stopping for drinks on the way home, and posting pictures about it on your boss's Facebook page **is** a bad idea.

---

In order for the plural to be used in the original, it would need to be rephrased to make other elements plural too:

> ...carrying out attacks on the VC's residence, office, vandalism as well as disrupting classes and university activities in the name of movement **are** also ***kinds*** of terror ***acts***.

Alternatively, a phrase could be inserted to bridge the plural and singular:

> ...carrying out attacks on the VC's residence, office, vandalism as well as disrupting classes and university activities in the name of movement **are** also ***examples of*** one kind of terror act.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the excerpt is not a sentence. I will take the independent clause starting with "vandalism" as a sentence to answer your question.

**Vandalism** is also one kind of terror act.

**Vandalism**, as well as disrupting classes and university activities in the name of movement, is also one kind of terror act.

> ...vandalism as well as disrupting classes and university activities in the name of movement is also one kind of terror act.

As you can see, when you remove the parenthetical you arrive at the subject "vandalism" which is singular, so you should use "is" not "are."

Comment: No. You have restructured the original sentence. The subject of the original is a sequence of elements joined in a list. Its grammatical number is therefore plural and **are** should be used. (In other words, the original is wrong.)

Comment: You claim the original is wrong because it should be using "are" instead of "is" with absolutely no source whatsoever. The original could have just as easily been wrong because it used a comma instead of the word "or" in between the words "residence" and "office." In that case, the sentence should not use "are": "[In addition to] carrying out attacks on the VC's residence or office, vandalism as well as disrupting classes...in the name of movement is also one kind of terror act." Furthermore, it makes no sense to say something "*are* one kind of terror act" because ONE is singular.

Comment: Sources are plentiful, but [here is one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_subject#:~:targetText=Compound%20subjects%20joined%20by%20%E2%80%9Cand,is%20available%20in%20the%20cafeteria.%E2%80%9D). It is true that "... are one kind of..." is then awkward in this case, but it is _not_ ungrammatical. If you would like to compose a question about that I'd be happy to provide a more detailed and sourced answer.

Comment: @TypeIA - The original sentence is poorly written.  No clarification can be extracted from the morass.  Junk sentence leads to junk analysis.